# Symfony2 - Doctrine-extension - Loggable with User

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Loggable of doctrine extension (Doc here : https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md ) and that work fine :)

But this extension use "username" to identified the User but me i want use ManyToOne relation with User Entity (so use user_id).

How do I do that?

Thks

Olivier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have a hard time with that, You would have to overwrite a lot of the Loggable functionality.

I would recommend implementing the `getUsername` function and just returning the string version of the user_id.

```
//UserEntity
public function getUsername()
{
    return (string)$this->user_id;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i'll do that :) I never use le username ;)